# Setting a bitmap using RemoteView not working

Tags: android, android-widget

Im writing a widget and I need to download and set a bitmap on the layout.  Everything I've tried doesn't seem to work.

I've created a test bitmap now to set on the view, [update] this works.

```
  Bitmap.Config config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
  Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageActiveWidth, imageHeight, config); 
  Canvas canvas =  new Canvas(bitmap); // Load the Bitmap to the Canvas
  Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setColor(0xFFFFCCFF);
  canvas.drawRect(0, 0, imageActiveWidth, imageHeight, paint); 
  views.setImageViewBitmap(resId, bitmap);
```

using a resource file does work:

```
  Bitmap placeholderBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.placeholder_medium);
  views.setImageViewBitmap(imageSlotId, placeholderBitmap);
```

However using a downloaded bitmap does not seem work. 
(after async task has downloaded bitmap, I have a method setBitmap which is one line:

```
 views.setImageViewBitmap(resId, proxy);
```

Result - screen is just white, no bitmap

I'm really stumped on how to get this to work, because I need to be able to download bitmaps and set them.

Comment: Okay so silly mistake - my test wasn't working because of not accounting for alpha in paint!  should have been:
                    `Paint p = new Paint();
                    p.setColor(0xFFFF0000);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a solution.  I think its related to this bug:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8489

Solved by changing by setBitmap method to the following:

```
private void setBitmap(RemoteViews views, int resId, Bitmap bitmap){
    Bitmap proxy = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(proxy);
    c.drawBitmap(bitmap, new Matrix(), null);
    views.setImageViewBitmap(resId, proxy);
}
```

And I needed to call:
 `AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);`
 **AFTER the bitmaps had been set.**

For some reason this wasn't working when I came back to it.  My view was an AdapterViewFlipper, so i used the above method with a call to `widgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId, R.id.content);` which caused the bitmaps to render.

Comment: Calling updateAppWidget(...) AFTER I loaded my image was the solution for me.  Thanks!